# Does Adobe Acrobat XI Pro have a tooltip feature?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Does Adobe Acrobat XI Pro have a feature that allows you to hover over text or an entry field (or anything) -- and display hover-over help info. This would not be on a web page.

This would be a form sent to customers with editable fields.

Answer (score 2):

#### Does Adobe have a feature that allows you to hover over text or an entry field and display help info?

What you are looking for is a **Tooltip**.

---

#### Tooltips for Form Fields

> For accessibility, the Tooltip option on the General tab is important for entering text that will be announced by screen readers.
>
> You can make form fields accessible to people with disabilities by adding tags to the PDF and by properly structuring it. In addition, you can use the tool tip form field property to provide the user with information about the field or to provide instructions. For example, using the tool tip property value, the screen reader could say “Your first name.” Without the tool tip property, a screen reader announces the type and name of the form field

[image]

> - If necessary, choose Forms > Add or Edit Fields, and make sure that the Select Object tool is selected.
> - Double-click a selected form field to open the Properties window.
> - In the General tab, type a description into the tool tip box.
>
> The Tooltip also displays text that users may find helpful in filling in the form field. Tooltips appear when the pointer hovers briefly over the form field.

You can also create ToolTips for Radio Buttons. See the source link below for more information.

Source [Adobe® Acrobat® 9 Pro Accessibility Guide: Creating Accessible Forms](http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/acrobat/pdf/A9-creating-accessible-pdf-forms.pdf)

---

#### Further Reading

- [PDF Accessibility -Accessible Forms in Acrobat XI](http://webaim.org/techniques/acrobat/forms)